# MySQL join two tables in the same row on different column

Tags: mysql, inner-join, between

I'm going to join two table with the same destination but different origin value. I'm sure I'm not good in explain in words. But hopefully you're going to get what I want by my code below:

**MySQL**

```
SELECT 
option_places_db.plc_en AS from_en, 
option_places_db.plc_th AS to_en, 
concat( time_start_hr, ':', time_start_min ) AS time1, 
concat( time_end_hr, ':', time_end_min ) AS time2, 
price_adult, 
price_child
FROM `time_table_boat`
INNER JOIN option_places_db ON time_table_boat.org = option_places_db.plc_id
ORDER BY time_table_boat.org ASC
```

**time_table_boat**
[image]

**option_places_db**

[image]

According to time_table_boat table. I expect :

```
from_en    to_en     time1    time2    price_adult    price_child
Aonang     Phi Phi   09:00    11:00    450            350
Phi Phi    Aonang    15:30    17:00    450            350
```

But from running mySQL it turned something like this instead:
[image]

The column 'to_en' is not match with the time_table_boat.des=option_places_db (=3) as it should be. I've tried to add more line of inner join but it comes up with error of the same destination table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    org_places.plc_en AS from_en, 
    des_places.plc_en AS to_en, 
    CONCAT( time_start_hr, ':', time_start_min ) AS time1, 
    CONCAT( time_end_hr, ':', time_end_min ) AS time2, 
    price_adult, 
    price_child
FROM `time_table_boat`
INNER JOIN 
    option_places_db AS org_places ON time_table_boat.org = org_places.plc_id
INNER JOIN 
    option_places_db AS des_places ON time_table_boat.des = des_places.plc_id
ORDER BY time_table_boat.org ASC
```

Comment: Do I need to create another table named 'des_places'?

Comment: No, you just give diffrent alias for option_places_db. One of them use for origin, the other for destination.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT
placeOrg.plc_en AS from_en, 
placeDes.plc_th AS to_en, 
concat( time_start_hr, ':', time_start_min ) AS time1, 
concat( time_end_hr, ':', time_end_min ) AS time2, 
price_adult, 
price_child
FROM `time_table_boat`
INNER JOIN option_places_db AS placeOrg ON time_table_boat.org = placeOrg.plc_id
INNER JOIN option_places_db AS placeDes ON time_table_boat.des= placeDes.plc_id
ORDER BY time_table_boat.org ASC
```

You want two different names from the table option_places_db so you need to join it twice. First time to retrieve the origin name and second time to retrieve the destination name.
You can see you use the same table for origin and destination, you just link them twice et give it a temporary name to differentiate the response you get.

EDIT: corrected the query

Comment: your solution seems to work but
`#1054 - Unknown column 'time_table_boat.dest' in 'on clause'`
Thank you.

Comment: Yeah you are right sorry, had written .destination before checking the name you chose and forgot a t. Nice catch !